# JavaScript: getElementsByTagName returns empty nodeList

Tags: javascript, iframe, gmail

I'm trying the following code on the main gmail page:

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById('canvas_frame');

var innerDoc = (iFrame.contentDocument) ? iFrame.contentDocument : iFrame.contentWindow.document;

var tag = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('vI8oZc cS');
```

tag always comes up as an empty nodeList.  I'm checking this in the debugger and I can see one of the first divs is of this class type "vI8oZc cS".  How can I get the node element and not an empty list?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName` ?

Comment: Have you tried with `innerDoc.querySelectorAll('.vI8oZc.cS');`?

Comment: Actually, I have tried all 3 (getElementsByClassName, getElementsByTagName and querySelectorAll) with the same result - empty nodeList.

Comment: What does `innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('vI8oZc'); return?
`

Comment: @Jahmic Then the problem is like that: there are no elements responding to your criteria. It's as simple as that. Try to dump `innerDoc.body.innerHTML` for confirmation.

Comment: @MaxArt It's possible, but on my breakpoint, I break down the nodes of the innerDoc and I can find the class, I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The browser security policies don't allow such actions if the source of the iframe isn't on the same site the parent page on.

Comment: Actually I kinda recognize those classes - are those from GMail or other Google app?

Comment: Yes, they look like a classes from Gmail. And @Jahmic said about it in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: @khomyakoshka This might be related or ultimately playing a major factor.  But this is part of an user approved 'injected userscript', which part of the intent is get around such permissions.

Comment: @Jahmic, sorry, it was not enough clear from your post. But now I've tried to run this userscript in the Firefox and it works.